# Forwarding Variables and Other Info between HTML Documents

Tags: javascript, php, html, function

I think it is a rather basic question, but because I am brand new to front-end.. Not sure how to properly execute it. What I'm doing: Making a little project which a small part of is the login. I log in to my page, it checks a database, if the name and password are correct, it will Login giving access to multiple different pages/html documents based on the actual project

What I want to understand how to-do: I was looking to just save that first initial Login (ID) as a variable, so at the top of the page always displaying the person logged in... Kinda like any other basic login page feature.

How exactly do I save that variable in my javascript, and send it over to every new HTML page on the website? I am unsure if this can be done solely through javascript, or if I should be saving it somehow using database/php and sending it back. Thank you for any help you provide!

Just some code to help work with variable names and see how things are sent/received.

```
<script>
  function ajaxLoginFunction(){
  var ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){

      var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('ajaxDiv')
      var res = ajaxRequest.innerHTML = this.responseText;

      //login as a student or teacher variables to redirect
      var student_page="studentview.html";
      var teacher_page="teacherview.html";
      var data=JSON.parse(res)

      //ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = (data['questions']['question'][2].toString());
      if (data['type']=="student") window.location.replace(student_page);
        else if(data['type']=="teacher") window.location.replace(teacher_page);
            else ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = "Login Failed";

        }
    };
    //storing my id and password to be sent to database
    //which sends back the info for student/teacher redirect pages
    var ucid = document.getElementById('username').value;
    var pass = document.getElementById('password').value;
    var login = "login";
    //how would i hold onto the ucid after logging in and redirecting to another url?
    var myObj = {id: login, usr: ucid, pwd: pass};
    var myJSON = JSON.stringify(myObj);

    ajaxRequest.open("POST","https://myphpfile.php", true);
    ajaxRequest.send(myJSON);
}
</script>
```

Comment: You can save it in localStorage if you want.

Comment: Why not to use PHP session? If you have to show only HTML pages, you can make a script in PHP and on page load check if the user is logged or not by AJAX request.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend cookies, though you can also use session variables. Cookies might be the best route if you've got your mind set on using JS exclusively. Although, PHP has some nice tools for both.

```
// JS COOKIE CREATION
function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays) {
  var d = new Date();
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
  var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
  document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}

// PHP COOKIE CREATION
setcookie(<cookie name>, <cookie value>, <expiration>, <access - '/' for all site pages>);
```

Check if cookie exists...

```
// JS COOKIE CHECK
function getCookie(cname) {
  var name = cname + "=";
  var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
  var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
  for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
      c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
      return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
  }
  return ""; // If no cookie 'cname' exists
}

// PHP COOKIE CHECK
$_COOKIE[<cookie name>] // Will return cookie value; use isset() to verify cookie has been set
```

On each 'restricted' page, check to see if the cookie exists and grant access if so; if not, redirect them to the login page or show some other message. To delete a cookie, or 'Log Off', set the expiration to before today (negative expiration date). Or, just set a blank cookie value. I use a browser extension (EditThisCookie on Chrome) to do testing and see the value of stored cookies. You can store multiple cookies if you'd like - one for username, another for user type - or handle differentiating between 'teachers' and 'students' another way. Remember not to store passwords locally. i.e. don't put the password in a cookie.

PHP sessions would be great to look into, also. Tons of documentation all over the place. Session variables would work perfectly for what you're trying to accomplish...

```
// PHP SESSION VARIABLE EXAMPLES
  $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user->username; // ucid
  $_SESSION['priv'] = $user->type; // 'teacher' or 'student'
```

Similar to the cookie approach, on each 'restricted' page you would put a bit of PHP to check the session for ID and access type. Being PHP, none of this information would be stored locally, which gives you bonus points for security and whatnot.